# How to concatenate all YES records into a single list?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, list, concatenation

How do I combine all "Yes" records into a single list?  I have the following script that I would like to combine into a single varchar list, ideally using XML or a native SQL function.  These values are either a 1 or a 0.  I want these values to only appear if they are a 1:

```
select
x.Energetic,
x.Undistressed,
x.Wellnourished,
x.Goodhygiene

From
health_x x
```

In this example, if Energetic and Wellnourished were 1 and the others 0, then I would want this to display as:

```
Energetic, Wellnourished
```

Comment: TSQL seems like a bad place to do this. Do you want a comma delimited list per row?

Comment: Do you want this done row by row?  Or do you want it done for all rows in the table?

Comment: I want to merge all rows into one single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional concatenation.

The trick is getting the separator character put in correctly.  This version puts `,` before each string, and then uses `stuff()` to get rid of the first occurrence:

```
select STUFF((case when x.Energetic = 1 then ', Energetic' else '' end) +
             (case when x.Undistressed = 1 then ', Undistressed' else '' end) +
             (case when x.Wellnourished = 1 then ', Wellnourished' else '' end) +
             (case when x.Goodhygiene = 1 then ', Goodhygiene' else '' end),
             1, 2, ''
            )
from health_x x
```

Comment: This will create as many lists as there are records in the table. I think OP wants a single list.

Comment: @Aryadev . . . That is not how I interpret the question.  The phrase "if Energetic and Wellnourished were 1 and the others 0, then I would want this to display as . . ." makes me think the OP wants it done row by row. Let's see what the OP says.

Answer (score 1):

```
select stuff((
select 
case when x.Energetic = 1 then ', Energetic' else '' end + 
case when x.Undistressed = 1 then ', Undistressed' else '' end + 
case when x.Wellnourished = 1 then ', Wellnourished' else '' end + 
case when x.Goodhygiene = 1 then ', Goodhygiene' else '' end

From
health_x x
for xml path('')
),1,2,'');
```